# Expresión regular que haga match cuando un número sea de 10 dígitos y comience con 1558 o cuando un número sea de 12 dígitos y comience con 310

Tags: javascript, regex

Hola comunidad estoy tratando de crear una expresión regular que haga match si cumple las siguientes condiciones:

```
-Debe contener 10 dígitos e iniciar con 1558
-Debe contener 12 dígitos e iniciar con 310
```

Por ejemplo:

```
1558218374 True
1559218374 False
1234567899 False
2155817896 False
310123456789 True
311123456789 False
131023456789 False
123456789999 False
```

he intentando con esta expresión regular :

```
^[1558]\d{10}$|^[310]\d{12}$
```

Pero no logro que me funcione. Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Gracias pero no me funcionó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que dichos números ocupen toda la línea (es decir, que cada número comience al principio de la línea y que los mismos estén separados por saltos de línea) usa la siguiente regex:

```
/^((1558[0-9]{6})|(310[0-9]{9}))$/gm
```

link para probarla: [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/qo6R3k/1)

para negar la expresión es un poco más complejo porque no se bajo qué condiciones debo hacerlo, voy a asumir que buscas los números de 10 o 12 dígitos que no comiencen con 1558 y 310 respectivamente, para ayudarte podes usar 'negative lookahead' que son los símbolos '?!' :

```
/^(?!1558)\d{10}(?!\d)|^(?!310)\d{12}$/gm
```

link para probarla: [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/NoQ5jU/1)

Comment: Gracias @infinit3loop y cómo hago para negarlo, que marqué los que estan false y no los True.

Comment: dame un momento

Comment: Gracias muy útil me ha funcionado

Comment: @YeynerOsmarEscobar si te sirvió márcala como útil con el signo ✓. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
^(1558)[\d]{6}|^(310)[\d]{9}
```

^  -> debe iniciar con lo que sigue.
() -> debe contener esto.
{} -> de lo anterior, esta cantidad.

Comment: Hola Marce Puente, no me resalta todo el digito, cómo hago para que lo resalte todo. Agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Entendí mal, cambia el "10" por "6" y el "12" por "9".

Comment: Sigue igual @Marce Puente: link https://regex101.com/r/B6E8WX/1

Comment: @Yeyner Osmar Escobar, por suerte está la respuesta de infinit3Loop__, perdón por los errores cometidos, ahora debería funcionar.